# S3 Multi-part Upload --expected-size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm currently working on uploading a file with a size greater than 5GB to S3 by streaming directly from another program into the AWS CLI.

This means I have to pass the `--expected-size` parameter but I don't know the size of the file in advance, and it's bigger than the disk on the machine so I can't examine it.

I currently pass a larger number "just to be safe" but as time goes on this file may grow beyond this, and I don't want to have to keep updating my script.

Are there any adverse consequences of specifying an "expected size" of the current maximum for a file (4TB) or some other size many times greater than my current one even if I don't think I'll approach that limit?

Comment: This is a good question.  Intuitively, it seems likely that this parameter might have implications on the size of any temp files created, so in a space-constrained environment, that could be problematic.

Comment: While I'm no closer to finding out the solution, an expected size of 5TB - much bigger than my actual file and the biggest S3 will allow had no detrimental effect, and would operate with a very full disk so it is unlikely to be creating any significant temporary files.